# How to create facebook login for Django website ?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to create facebook login for facebook login page,  I'm using facebook Javascript SDK , so Imtry this code

```
 function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  console.log("response "+response);
  for (var key in response)
  {

    console.log(key +":" + response[key]);

  }


});
 }
```

In console I get

id:10204323190254715

first_name:Ivan

gender:male

last_name:Blazevic

link:https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10204323190254715/

locale:en_US

name:Ivan Blazevic

timezone:1

updated_time:2014-08-10T12:12:37+0000

verified:true

Is possible to get email, password,place and other information from facebook user..  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get password... how do you imagine that?! This is **not** how OAuth or any social-based works!

For rest of fields, yes you can. You should inform facebook first that you need that information, so facebook can ask user for proper permissions.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2?locale=pl_PL) is more information about that.